# help with a possible rotation

Tags: geometry

If i make this "rotation" (-y, -x) what type of rotation is it, if it is at all?

Comment: What are the "types" of rotations? Did you apply it to a couple of strategic points in the plane and see where they landed? With what definition of "rotation" are you you supposed to check "if it is at all" a rotation? There's a lot of questions raised by the question itself. Also "How do I analyze this rotation?" or "Is $(x,y)\mapsto (-y,-x)$ a rotation?" are far more advisable titles than "help with ROTATION" for a number of reasons.

Comment: This is a reflection, not a rotation. A reflection has a line of points that stay fixed under the operation, while a rotation of the plane (other that the zero rotation) does not. (The line is $x+y=0$.) (You can think of a reflection in the plane as a rotation in the third dimension, I suppose.)

Comment: Do you mean from $(x,y)$ to $(-y,-x)$?

Comment: yeah i meant (x,y) to(-y, -x)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Why do you say that $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ is not a rotation?

Comment: That matrix is similar to $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$ which is a reflection, not a rotation. It has negative determinant, and all rotations have determinant=1.. @AlexM.

Comment: It would really help to answer your question to know what you mean by "type of rotation." @RobertMcDonald

Answer (score 0):

In 2 dimensions it's not a rotation, but in 3 dimensions it is.

Rotate by 180 degrees about the axis $y=-x$ and you'll make this transformation.  This is cheating a bit since we have to hide z in order to make this work.  If z was included we would have
$(x,y,z) \rightarrow (-y,-x,-z)$